# Creating richer speedometer gauge charts for dashboards in R/R-studio?

Tags: r, rstudio, shinydashboard

Please can you help me? Can anyone help me/guide me on how I can create speedometer gauges like the image below using R/R-studio? I want to move away from depending on Excel, especially as my datasets are quite large. Thanks in advance :)

[image: Current Speedometer charts that I want to move into R]

Comment: You got those speedometers from Excel?? Wow, they've made some changes since I last tried ... to determine my speed ... in Excel. http://dilbert.com/strip/1997-09-10

Comment: Haha yeah I manually built these on excel (they arent prebuilt charts in excel). ALthogh credit goes to PKExpert channel on YouTube from which I adapted the concept for my use :)

Answer (score 3):

Try using `gvisGauge()` from the `googlevis` package, e.g. this picture from [this blog post](http://www.grroups.com/blog/r-visualizing-plan-crash-data-using-some-interesting-graphscharts-including-googlevis-and-great-circle-ones):

[image]

which uses this code:

```
Gauge <-  gvisGauge(m1, 
           options=list(min=0, max=20000, greenFrom=0,
                        greenTo=5000, yellowFrom=5000, yellowTo=15000,
                        redFrom=15000, redTo=20000, width=800, height=800))
#
plot(Gauge)
```